# C# Automatically Rename a File with the Current Date and Time if the File Already Exists

Tags: c#, streamwriter, file-rename

My C# code is generating a text file with a content that is being fetched from the db and saving those in a folder. Every time when I run the code, it overrides the existing file.

Here is my code.

```
StreamWriter file = new StreamWriter(@"C:\ExportedData\myFile.txt");
file.WriteLine(sb.ToString());     
file.Close();
```

Ideally, I would want to keep all the files and append each file's name with current date and time.

Comment: Have you looked into using DateTime.Now for your timestamp?

Comment: Yes, I did, but didn't know how to add that to the streamWriter. As per Adam's response, '$' does the job. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `DateTime.Now.ToString()` method to generate a string representation of the current date and time and include that in the filename you're producing. The $ at the start of this string lets you add parameters inline using variables or code expressions inside curly brackets.

```
Console.WriteLine($@"C:\ExportedData\myFile_{DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")}.txt");
```

Comment: Thank you, Adam! Understood!
It worked perfectly fine!